# Do I use `pyvenv` or `virtualenv` for creating a virtual environment?

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtual-environment

Some guides mention `pyvenv` (***not*** `pyenv`) when talking about virtual environments such as [the official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html). Others mention `virtualenv` such as in [the Hitchhiker's Guide to Python](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/). I've tried `pyvenv` and I think that it worked as you can see:

[image]

and these are the contents of `ve` directory:

[image]

So can `pyvenv` be used to create virtual environments? Does `virtualenv` do the same as `pyvenv`? Which one should better be used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are very much alike. The main difference is that `virtualenv` has been around for a long time, and can be used in most setups.

`pyvenv`, on the other hand, was designed for Python3, and ships with the standard library since version `3.4`.

In other words, `virtualenv` is the classic choice, while `pyvenv` is a recent addition to the standard library. I suppose `pyvenv` will eventually replace `virtualenv` (as soon as Python 3 replaces Python 2 :P)

Comment: Almost true. `pyvenv` is not part of standard library while `venv` is since Python 3.3 as the official documentation says.

Comment: Here's the link to the documentation of `venv`, for the record: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Answer (score 3):

`pyvenv` is basically a wrapper around [venv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) which is part of standard library since Python 3.3 and is the recommended way of creating virtual enviromnents since then. And actually `pyvenv` wrapper is not so recommended. On Python >= 3.3 consider using `venv` module directly as described in linked docs. Older Python versions should use `virtualenv` to create virtual environments.

Answer (score 1):

How you create a virtual environment depends upon whether you are using Python 3 or 2.

- [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) is a tool to create isolated Python environments. It can be used with Python 2 and 3.
- `pyvenv` was introduced in Python 3.3, it was [deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) since Python 3.6 in favor of using `python3 -m venv`, and it is scheduled to disappear in Python 3.8.

As practical advice, use the following to create a virtual environment called `venv` depending on your Python version:

```
$ virtualenv venv # in Python 2 
$ python3 -m venv venv # Python 3
```

Regardless of which Python version you use, a folder `venv` containing the files of the virtual environment will be created.